# Why does f.write() in a Python file on a server not work?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, logging, ssh, virtualenv

I have a Python app that works locally, but on the server something goes wrong. 
So I have to do some debugging in an SSH session. 
The server logs tell me that something goes wrong in `utils/do_something.py`. 
I have created `utils/log` (rights 777), where the debugging values are supposed to go.

`do_something.py` looks like this:

```
import os
parent_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
log_file = os.path.join(parent_folder, 'log')

def do_something(arg1, arg2):

    print('XXX')
    f = open(log_file, 'a')
    f.write('XXX\n')

    stuff = goes.wrong
```

Loading the page causes `do_something` to run (as confirmed by the error logs). Locally the expected *XXX* appears in the console and in the log file. But nothing happens on the server.

I created a second file `utils/blah.py`:

```
print('BLAH')

import os
parent_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
log_file = os.path.join(parent_folder, 'log')
f = open(log_file, 'a')
f.write('BLAH\n')
```

When I run it with `python blah.py`, the expected *BLAH* appears in the console and the logfile.

I don't care that much about the difference between local and production server.
But I would like to understand the difference between `do_something.py` and `blah.py`.

Is there a better way to debug in an SSH session?

I work in a virtualenv in a `mod_wsgi 4.6.5/Python3.7` environment on a Webfaction server. 
Some details about it can be seen in [this question](https://community.webfaction.com/questions/21924/please-share-the-httpdconf-of-a-working-django-app-using-virtualenv.<br) on the Webfaction forum.

---

**Edit 1:** On the server `print` seems to be discouraged anyway.
(See [Where do things go when I ‘print’ them from my Django app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182298/where-do-things-go-when-i-print-them-from-my-django-app))
But what matters to me is `f.write()`. I just added `print` for comparison.

**Edit 2:** It is the same when I use the logging module. It works when I run `blah.py`, but nothing happens when loading the page runs `do_something`.

**Edit 3:** I tried the same with a simpler app, and the result is the same.
I added the logging in `views.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import os

parent_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
log_file = os.path.join(parent_folder, 'log')

def home_view(request):
    f = open(log_file, 'a')
    f.write('XXX\n')
    return HttpResponse("Hello from home view.")
```

Locally this writes *XXX* to the log file every time the page is loaded. But not on the server.
There are no errors in the server log.

---

**Using the `logging` module:** I am not sure why that did not work, but now it does.

```
import os
import logging

parent_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
log_file = os.path.join(parent_folder, 'log')
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file, level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This works.')
```

Possibly I have used it with `filename='log'` instead of `filename=log_file`.
Locally the former creates the log file in the root folder. But on the server it must already exist.

**Writing rights**: It seems worth mentioning that `touch log` gave me a file I could not wright to, and lacking `sudo` I could not use `chmod`. So I used the trick `install -b -m 777 /dev/null log`.

Comment: Did you restart the Django server after modifying `do_something`?

Comment: I restarted the Apache server with `./apache2/bin/restart`. The line numer in the error log shows that it is the `do_something.py` with the logging code added.

Comment: _"The server logs tell me that something goes wrong in utils/do_something.py."_ - what does that mean? Are you literally getting a server warning of "something went wrong"? Are you getting a specific error message? If so, what's the error message?

Comment: I just mentioned that to explain why I have to debug on the server. But details about a different problem would not help solving this one. As mentioned in edit 3, the problem is the same in a different app, where I don't get any errors.

Comment: It appears you never close the file. Have you tried explicitly closing the file and/or flushing the file descriptor? Perhaps the output is just buffered.

Comment: Is the file even created?

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley. Closing the file did the trick. Locally that was never necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you never explicitly close the file after writing, so the output is probably buffered. Your server and your local machine may have different settings with respect to file buffering, which would explain the differences you're experiencing.

If you want to open, write, and close a file, python's context managers are the best way to do it:

```
def home_view(request):
    with open(log_file, 'a') as f:
        f.write('XXX\n')
    return HttpResponse("Hello from home view.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might check the privileges on the utils folder, and on any parent folders.  Many times an http server will be running as user 'nobody', which has practically zip privileges.  So unless the utils folder itself also has 0777 privileges, that could create a problem.  You also might want to put the f.write in a try ... except block so that you can catch the error specifically and create a more useful / informative message about the error.  Best.

Comment: I also assumed that this is about rights, but it is not. As I mentioned the `log` file is 777. So is the `utils` folder. This problem is already solved. Maybe you have to reload the page to see the accepted answer above.